# Does using a navigation collection property in a .Where predicate require explicit hydration?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Say I have two models/tables.

```
public class ParentEntity 
{
    public Guid ID { get; set;}
    
    public List<ChildEntity> ChildEntities { get; set; } // navigation property
}

public class ChildEntity 
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    
    public Guid ParentEntityID { get; set; }  // foreign key
}
```

If I run a query like this:

```
var parentEntities = await _context.ParentEntities.Where(x => x.ChildEntities.Any()).ToListAsync();
```

From what I can tell (based mostly on experimentation), this query does not require explict hydration of ChildEntities (using `.Include(x => x.ChildEntities)`).

If I wanted to do something with the ChildEntities outside of the query/after the list is materialized, I **would** need to explicitly hydrate ChildEntities:

```
var parentEntities = await _context.ParentEntities.Include(x => x.ChildEntities)
                                                  .Where(x => x.ChildEntities.Any()).ToListAsync();
                                                  
foreach (var parentEntity in parentEntities) 
{
    foreach (var childEntity in parentEntities) 
    {
        // do something with childEntity
    }
}
```

That's my understanding, anyway, and that's how it seems to work. However, I'm hoping to find some Microsoft documentation that mentions this explicitly. I haven't been able to find anything (all the search keywords I can think to use point me in the direction of [Filtered Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include), which is NOT what I'm wondering about).

I want to be confident that my understanding is correct, and that I haven't just gotten "lucky" by the child entities already being hydrated from other queries in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

`Include` needed ONLY for loading related entities and ONLY for such purpose. It has no affect on filter or projection. You can omit `Include` if you do not plan to load related entities.

Comment: That's basically what I've figured out with trial and error. Do you know how/where I can find documentation about this?

Comment: It is defined in documentation [Eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#eager-loading). And there is no mention that you have to use `Include` for filtering. I don't know why people still put `Include` everywhere without understanding for which purpose this operator was introduced.

Comment: Fir filter EF Core just uses navigation property metadata information and creates SQL, that's all. `Include` information is NOT used for that. But when EF Core is materialising WHOLE entity, it checks which Includes are specified and creates additional JOINs to retrieve related data. Only on that step.